# Existence of constant function on analytic manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be an analytic manifold and let $\gamma \subset M$ be a geodesic curve and let $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-constant and analytic function.

Prove or disprove that

If $f(\gamma)$ is constant then $f(M)$ is constantm, which implies that $M$ must be constant ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean by $M$ be constant?

Comment: In $M=\mathbb{C}^2$ take $f(x,y)=x$. Then $f=0$ on all of $\{x=0\}$, yet $f$ is not constant on $M$.

Comment: I mean that $M$ is a constant hyperplane.

Comment: Dear @SphericalTriangle thanks for your answer. I think it is a simple counter-example.